# Acer notebook Aspire One D255E

Tags: windows-7

When I try to type the question mark it does not work and my apostrophes and quotation marks do not work. When I try to type the question mark I get this instead É.

Comment: Please [edit] you post into the form of a question. As it is, it may be closed for not being a real question.

Answer (score 0):

Check your language settings to make sure that they are set to English.

You can do this:

1. From control panel->region and language->keyboards and languages->change keyboards...
   Remove the non-english languages.
2. Alternative, try pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>
3. Alternatively, check bottom right on the task bar if there is a language setting you can change.